# How to identify load(thread group and connection time out) bottleneck by using jmeter generated reports from non-gui

Tags: jmeter

How to identify load (thread user & connection timeout) bottleneck by using jmeter generated reports from non-gui.

Steps I have done:

1. Imported *.jmx in jmeter which was recorded by using blazemeter pulgin.
2. I had set the duration assertion, uniform random timer.
3. Set Thread group to 100 threads and ramp-up to 50 seconds.
4. I have installed perfmon in respective server and added perfmon listener in this thread group.
5. I have saved and closed test plan and jmeter gui.
6. I executed the saved test plan in non-gui.
7. Once execution stopped I converted saved *.csv to html.

By using above html report, how can I find thread group (load) bottleneck. If you want me to increase the load (thread group) then please explain me after increasing the load(virtual users) how can i identify the load(thread group) bottleneck.

PFB  HTML reports from that give solution for me to find thread group (load) bottleneck.

**Transactions per second**
[image]

**Codes per second** 
[image]